# Slow Indexing in Magento EE 1.12

Tags: magento, indexing

We have 4000 products with 4 stores and around 80 categories. We are running a dedicated DB server having SSD and followed the white paper of optimizing DB as well as App Server. Each product also have 12 custom options. Now Indexing is very slow. Any suggestions. Would it make any difference to reduce number of categories in the store etc.

Regards,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is dramatically slowed when multi store setups are used. On one of our servers 3000 products on a single store setup takes approx 60 seconds to index everything. But 3000 products on a multi store setup (7 stores) can take up to 10 minutes. We have it set up to manual index only. You could set the indexing to run on a cron which might help you. (Throwing more resources at the server will obviously help too).

Comment: 1 trick did it for me. Now I truncate the core_url_rewrite table and then run the indexing. Somehow the whole process is completed within few min. I am also contacting Magento to find out if this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce Catalog price rules if in use
Reduce all attributes not required for Search Index - the default Magento install includes attributes like "Tax Status" in the Search Index and then this is multiplied 4x for your multi stores
Same can be said for URL rewrites - 4x increase

12 custom options per product ?  Could common attributes be used instead ?

Run indexing from SSH rather than from the Magento admin
In the web root in the shell/ folder you will find indexer.php
php indexer.php --help will give you some options
You can then time each of the nine indexes to see which is taking the most time which may help narrow the problem down
By running from command line you can increase the php memory limit just for that one process which may improve results

I set up a cron job to re-index the site in off peak times and in Magento admin, change to Manual Update only

Comment: Does reducing number of categories will help?

Comment: If I disable a category instead of deleting it, will it still index that category or skip it?